# Summing values within a time period in SQL ("rolling window")

Tags: sql, sql-server

let's say I have the following data:

```
ContactDate Zip   
10-1-2016   90210
10-7-2016   90211
10-8-2016   90210
10-8-2016   90211
```

I want to sum the number of contacts that occurred per zip during 30 day periods. However it's not by month, but the user's billing day of month. So lets say that day is the 2nd of each month...

I'm trying to get the following result:

```
BillingMonthStart Zip   Count
9-2-2016          90210 1
10-2-2016         90210 1
10-2-2016         90211 2
```

Here's my attempt (obviously the table structure is different, I'll start fixing the example above):

```
select 
    C1.ContactDate, count(C1.ContactDate)
from 
    dbo.contacts c1 join dbo.contacts C2 on 
        C2.contactdate between C1.ContactDate AND dateadd(day, 30, C1.ContactDate)
        AND c1.account = c2.accountid
    join payment.dbo.AccountBilling B  on c1.accountid = B.AccountID
where 
    c1.account = @accountid
    and C1.ContactDate >= @start_date
    and C1.ContactDate <= @end_date
    and DAY(C1.ContactDate) = B.BillingDOM
Group by C1.contactDate
```

The issue here is that if the account does get a contact on the billing day, I wont get a result for that month.

**EDIT**
First off, sorry for the poorly formed question. I've figured it out (although I'm sure there are better ways). Here's what I did:

1. get the billing month in a variable
2. Using a recursive CTE I generated all the billing dates (within a range I cared about)
3. Join on the Contact data table using `between` the billingDate from #2 and billingDate + 1 month
4. Group by the billing date and select the
   count.

Here's the SQL:

```
DECLARE @start_date DateTime
DECLARE @end_date DateTime
DECLARE @accountid int
DECLARE @billing_dom tinyint

SET @start_date = '2016-01-01' 
SET @end_date = '2016-12-31'
SET @accountid = 6045032;

select @billing_dom = BillingDOM
from Payment.dbo.AccountBilling
where AccountID = @accountid;


WITH cte_months AS
(
    SELECT
        BillingDate = CAST(CAST(datepart(yyyy, @start_date) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(datepart(mm, @start_date) AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@billing_dom AS varchar) AS DATETIME),
        dt = @start_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        BillingDate = DateAdd(mm, 1, BillingDate),
        dt = DATEADD(mm, 1, dt)
    FROM
        cte_months
    WHERE
        dt < DATEADD(mm, -1, @end_date)
)
--SELECT * FROM cte_months


select 
    cte_months.BillingDate, count(C.ContactDate) as Contacts
from 
    cte_months left join dbo.contacts C on 
        C.ContactDate between cte_months.BillingDate and dateadd(mm, 1, cte_months.BillingDate)
where 
    C.accountid = @accountid
Group by cte_months.BillingDate
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Can you explain how 9-2-2016  count is 1 for 90210?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy because the row on 10-1-2016 is part of that month.

Comment: @SeanLange I'll try to make my question more complete. As for now I've added my attempt at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could achieve this, using a case statement to group the data by the billing period. Without knowing exactly what your tables look like it's hard to know exactly what the select statement should be but the general concept still applies here:

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (ContactDate DATE, Zip INT);
INSERT @myTable VALUES ('10-1-2016', 90210), ('10-7-2016', 90211), ('10-8-2016', 90210), ('10-8-2016', 90211);

DECLARE @myBilling TABLE (Zip INT, BillingDay INT);
INSERT @myBilling VALUES (90210, 2), (90211, 2);

SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, T.ContactDate) < B.BillingDay 
            THEN DATEADD(DAY, B.BillingDay - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, T.ContactDate) - 1, 0))
            ELSE DATEADD(DAY, B.BillingDay - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, T.ContactDate), 0))
       END AS DATE) BillingPeriod
     , T.Zip
     , COUNT(*) theCount
FROM @myTable T
JOIN @myBilling B ON B.Zip = T.Zip  
GROUP BY T.Zip
        ,CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY, T.ContactDate) < B.BillingDay 
              THEN DATEADD(DAY, B.BillingDay - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, T.ContactDate) - 1, 0))
              ELSE DATEADD(DAY, B.BillingDay - 1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, T.ContactDate), 0))
         END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you grouping by month (28 to 31 days), or is it always 30 days?

If it is always 30 days then group by this in addition to any other non-date columns.

```
ceiling(cast(datediff(day,BillingMonthStart,ContactDate) AS FLOAT)/30)
```

This will give you the number of 30 days intervals between the BillingMonthStart and the ContactDate rounding up.  That said, it counts contact on the same day as 0 and is inclusive of the 30th day.  If you want the 30th day to be a new group then:

```
ceiling((cast(datediff(day,BillingMonthStart,ContactDate) AS FLOAT)+1)/30)
```

If you want this to be by month duration instead of a static 30 days then:

```
datediff(month,@BillingMonthStart,@ContactDate) - CASE
        WHEN datepart(day,@BillingMonthStart) > datepart(day,@ContactDate) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
```

Comment: by month. I've added a self answer at the top btw. Thanks for the help though